# UI template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like my users to be able to edit their own HTML/CSS for the specific template that they have selected.

This technique is used by Tumblr & Posterous, and I'm trying to research a few ways to implement it.

In a nutshell, I would like to define a layout by:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="header"></div>
     {Nav}
      <div id="middle">
           {Featured Article}
      </div>
</div>
```

ASP.NET MVC would then render a  for the tag {Nav} say:

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
</li>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

We stored user specified content in the database, so one approach I could take is storing the "whole page" in the database and parsing out the `{tag}` blocks before rendering it.

Is there something already built in MVC that would accomplish this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ASP.NET master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

You'd create a `MyMaster.master` file, like in the linked page, with the following content placeholders in the appropriate palce:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="Nav" runat="server" />
<asp:contentplaceholder id="FeaturedArticle" runat="server" />
```

Place that in `~/Views/Shared`, or possibly in a specific views folder if you want. In your `.aspx` view pages, you would reference that master page, like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MyMaster.master" %>
```

Then inside those views you would have

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Nav" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedArticle" runat="server">
    <!-- Other stuff here -->
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Domenic said - a Master Page can be used to declare one main layout and you could store/load the user specific content in the specific areas.

What I am not clear about - from your description - you say that a user can fill in the HTML/CSS for the template he selected. So I assume you may want to generate a number of layout templates a user can choose from and the user can then supply the content for each.

If you have a set of fixed general layouts then you could generate these as Master Pages and set them dynamically in the Controller View. Most Views in a Controller return a ViewResult which allows you to specify a MasterPage - meaning you can create a View whose MasterPage can be changed dynamically - based on the users preference.

Here is the ViewResult definition for ActionResult return type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.aspx